# Yarn not in path on Laradock worskpace when using it in inline docker exec command

Tags: docker, exec, workspace, yarnpkg, laradock

I have a problem using Laradock and yarn with an inline `docker exec` command from "outside" the `workspace` container.

When I use it from inside the `workspace` container, everything is working as expected :

```
docker exec -it --user=laradock laradock_workspace_1 bash
yarn -v
1.3.2
```

When I try to use it from an inline command, here is what happens :

```
docker exec -it --user=laradock laradock_workspace_1 yarn -v
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: \"yarn\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
For those who encounter the same issue, just use `docker exec` following the example below, in order to get access to node or yarn :

```
docker exec -it --user=laradock laradock_workspace_1 bash --login -c "yarn -v"
```

I found the solution here : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/82

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#apt-get install sudo -y
#sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
#sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
#apt-get remove node
#apt-get remove yarn
#curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
#sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
#curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
#echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
#sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
#apt-get remove node
#apt-get remove yarn
#curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
#sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
#curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
#echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
#sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
#yarn -v
1.13.0
#yarn install
```